# Extracting band values of an Image Collection over a point shapefile in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, reduceregion, value-extraction

I have an image collection in GEE consisting of 36 images, each with 23 bands of Sentinel 2 data (*S2L2A*).

I also have a point shapefile that I imported as an asset (*RAEJORDANESIA_POINT*).

I want to extract band values in these points and make a chart of it.
I wrote this script:

```
var RAEJORDANESIA_POINT = ee.FeatureCollection('users/parivash89/Eucalyptus_Brazil/RAE_JORDANESIA_1_2_arvores_perigosas_POINTS');
Map.addLayer(RAEJORDANESIA_POINT, {color: '#e73400',strokeWidth: 10}, 'RAEJORDANESIA_POINT');

var START = ee.Date('2021-11-01');
var FINISH = ee.Date('2022-04-29');

var ImageCollection = S2L2A
.filterDate(START,FINISH)
.filterBounds(RAEJORDANESIA_POINT);

Map.addLayer(ImageCollection, {min:0,max:3000,bands:"B4,B3,B2"}, 'ImageCollection');
print(ImageCollection)

var params = {
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  scale: 10,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  bands: ['B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A'],
  bandsRename: ['red-edge2', 'red-edge3', 'NIR', 'red-edge4']
};

// Extract zonal statistics per point per image.
var ptsStats = zonalStats(ImageCollection, RAEJORDANESIA_POINT, params);
print(ptsStats);
```

I found this script from https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/extract-raster-values-for-points

I get the error:

> Line 25: zonalStats is not defined

I also tried using **reduceRegions**:

```
var vals = ImageCollection.reduceRegions({
    collection: RAEJORDANESIA_POINT,
    reducer: 'mean',
    scale: 10, 
  })

print(vals)
```

And I got the error:

> Line 33: ImageCollection.reduceRegions is not a function

Here is the link with shared point asset [enter link description here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1dfe00691546ca50f42366b95ba61de3)

How can I extract all band values (mostly I am interested in NIR and red-edge bands) in these point and make a chart out of it for each point?

Comment: Thanks @user2856. I added the function and now I got error:FeatureCollection (Error)
Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements. Here is the new link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/adae07f337f8b251dbe9cfa20547c542

Comment: I have add params: var params = {
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  scale: 10,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  bands: ['B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8'],
  bandsRename: ['red-edge1','red-edge2', 'red-edge3', 'NIR', 'red-edge4']
};

Comment: I do not want to print or even export all bands and properties. I am just interested in these 5 bands

Comment: I deleted the print function and I tried to use Export to drive as follows:

Comment: Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ptsStats,
  description:'ExtractedValuesofPoints',
  folder: 'Brazil', 
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
  selectors: (["B5","B6","B7", "B8", "B8A" ])
});

Comment: But it exports an empty excel file with the first row the names of these 5 bands.

Comment: "Selector" works on properties and not band names I guess. If you see my image collection features, how can only 5 bands values for 36 images be shown?

Comment: All good comments! I would just add @user2856 that the number of features is calculated 36 images * 269 points. If it's more than 5000, you get an error. If it's 4999 - it will work. Number of bands does not matter. Other than that - really helpful insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to export the data, you can select the features you need in this way:

```
Export.table.toDrive({ collection: ptsStats, 
    description:'ExtractedValuesofPoints', 
    fileFormat: 'CSV', 
    selectors: (['red-edge2', 'red-edge3', 'NIR', 'red-edge4', 'datetime', '.geo'])})
```

The problem with empty file comes from selecting columns that don't exist (you use in the script  `bandsRename: ['red-edge2', 'red-edge3', 'NIR', 'red-edge4']` to rename `['B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8']`. Therefore, you need to use new band names in your export).

Also, I would recommend adding a date column too, as it may be helpful for your further analysis.

I hope this helps.